# Grothendieck duality for root stacks

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-stacks, serre-duality

Let $k$ be an algebraically closed field of characteristic $0$.
Let $X$ be a projective scheme over $k$, let $D = \sum_{i=1}^d$ be a simple normal crossing divisor.
Let ${\bf a} = (a_1,\cdots,a_d)$ be positive integers.

We denote $\sqrt[\bf a]{ {\bf D}/X} := \sqrt[a_1]{D_1/X} \times_X \cdots \times_X \sqrt[a_d]{D_d/X}$, where $\sqrt[a_i]{D_i/X}$ are the $a_i$-th root stack of $X$ associated to $D_i$.
We also denote $\tau:\sqrt[a]{ {\bf D}/X} \rightarrow X$ be the canonical morphism.

Then , the universal root divisor on $\sqrt[a_i]{D_i/X}$ is $\mathcal{D}_i := (\tau^{-1}D_i)_{red}$.

According to [Prop 3.4 in this paper by Fabio Nironi](https://arxiv.org/abs/0811.1955), then we have
$$
\tau^{!} \mathcal{F} \simeq \tau^{*}\mathcal{F} \left(\sum_{i=1}^d (a_i-1)\mathcal{D}_i \right)
$$
for all quasi-coherent sheaf of $X$.

**Question**: How can we prove this ?
(I can only find a slight sketch of the proof)

In addition, can we relax the condition about $D$ ?
For example, can we relax the condition "simple" ?

Thank you !
Any comment welcome !

**Edit**:(more about root stacks) we can find the construction of a root stack in [a paper by Borne](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0604458)  or [a paper by Cadman](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0312349v3).
The former (in section 3) mentions constructions related to uniform cyclic coverings.
The latter (in section 2) mentions those related to fiber product of classifying (or well-known) stacks.

Comment: Is the morphism $\tau$ lci? In that case, the line bundle in brackets would be the relative dualising sheaf of $\tau.$ You could then prove this locally, by constructing a canonical iso between the two sheaves in the model situation where the divisor is given by linear hyperplanes in affine space, and exploiting the fact that the iso is canonical to glue.

Comment: @DamianRössler  The morphism is LCI (etale locally), but it is not representable (neither by schemes nor by algebraic spaces).

Comment: @JasonStarr: But locally (even Zariski locally) over $X$ there is a cyclic covering $\tau' \colon X' \to X$ such that the root stack is the stack quotient of $X'$ by the cyclic group action. This can be used to prove the formula for $d = 1$, and then you can induct on $d$.

Comment: Thank you! 
Can we find details about the sketch Damian wrote in some references ?
And, how can we connect the idea Sasha said with Damian's argument ?